# How to skip the intent ui with Siri intent?

Tags: swift, sirikit

for example, after bring up Siri, it will ask the name of the song. The user will speak the name of the song and my app will just play the song. But looks like I have to press the intent extension ui to be able to run the app. Is there a way to go directly to the app after I provide/speak the parameters of the intent (or without showing the intent UI)?

It only goes to:

- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity {

after I press the intent UI.